# Different Permissions in Groups

Tags: 2013, permissions, master-page, administration

Working in SP13. I created a members group for my site and added the necessary individuals.  On the site I created a page that inherited the same group permissions as the parent.  However, there is one person that appears in the members group I do not want to have access to the page I created, but I want them to remain having access to the site.

One solution (that I think is not the best option) is to remove the group and add the names individually in the page permissions.  This is not a good idea, because this will require more maintaining if someone leaves.

Does anyone know how I can block this one person from the page listed in members group, but not removing them from having access to the main site?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit DENY when it comes to SharePoint permissions. In this case I would not use that particular group. I would create a new SharePoint group with all of the same members minus the individual(s) you do not want to have access to that page. I would stay away from assigning individual permissions on a user-to-user basis. You are absolutely correct that it becomes a bit of a maintenance nightmare when employees are onboarding, offboarding, or transferring to different positions in your company.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot achieve this as OOTB because you cannot assign distinct permissions to user in a Group. I.e if you create a SharePoint Group(defined at site collection level) and assign a permission level that will apply to  all the user who are members of the group.

What i am thinking, you can create another group called Members-1 and put the user in that group. Other possible way(which you dont like) add users individually.